# What class should I use to scrape the image link? I am working with scrapy and spider lib

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Here is the code I have written. All items are working excepts the product_imagelink

```
product_name = response.css('.product__name::text').extract()
    product_category = response.css('.product__group::text').extract()
    product_rarity = response.css('.product__extended-field::text').extract()
    product_imagelink = response.css('.product__details .product__image .img::attr(src)').extract()
    product_price = response.css('dd::text').extract()
```

Comment: Here's the source: https://imgur.com/EooYQ66 and here's the image of my entire code. https://imgur.com/F83kHlE

Comment: I want to be sure about your expectations. Do you want to extract the link of the image or do you want to extract the image itself?

Comment: Can we get more info about which libraries you are using and such?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser the tags: scrapy

Comment: @AvyWam Thanks for the comment. I want to extract the link of the image.

Comment: @QHarr I am not getting any error. Here's the result you can see: https://imgur.com/F83kHlE

Comment: what's the url please?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there should not be a . before the img as it is a type selector not class

```
product_imagelink = response.css('.product__details .product__image img::attr(src)').extract()
```

You can shorten to

```
product_imagelink = response.css('.product__image img::attr(src)').extract()
```